# Showing a measurement operator has a particular form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I came across an exercise (Ex 1.16) in 'Quantum Measurement and Control' by Wiseman and Milburn that I am having some trouble with.

Suppose we have some system $S$ coupled with two meters in states $|d_1\rangle,|d_2\rangle$. If $X$ and $P$ are the position and momentum operators choose units such that $[X,P]=i$, and let the system-meter coupling be given by:
$$U=\exp\left[-i(XP_1+PP_2)\right]$$

where the subscripts refer to operators on the two meters. Let their wavefunctions in the position representation be given by:
$$\langle x_j|d_j\rangle=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-1/4}e^{-x_j^2}$$

Following the interaction the detectors are measured projectively in the position basis, giving some result $(x_1,x_2)$. The effect this combined interaction + measurement of meters on the system $S$ can be described by some measurement operator:

$$M(x_1,x_2)=\langle x_1|\langle x_2|U|d_2\rangle|d_1\rangle$$

The question is to show that $M$ is equivalent to:
$$M(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}|(x_1,x_2)\rangle\langle(x_1,x_2)|$$
where the state $|(x_1,x_2)\rangle$ is the state with position probability amplitude distribution:
$$\langle x|(x_1,x_2)\rangle=(\pi)^{-1/4}\exp\left[ixx_2-\frac{1}{2}(x-x_1)^2\right]$$

I have tried writing out $M$ explicitly, and get:
$$M=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\iint dx_1'dx_2'\langle x_1|\langle x_2|\exp\left[-i(XP_1+PP_2)\right]e^{-(x_1'^2+x_2'^2)}|x_1'\rangle| x_2'\rangle$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here however. The operators in the exponential do not commute, and expanding it in a power series doesn't seem helpful as I can't deal with the $(XP_1+PP_2)^n$ term. Where should I go from here?

Comment: what are the algebraic properties of $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: $P_i$ is the momentum operator on meter $i$, so $[P_1,P_2]=[P_i,X]=[P_i,P]=0$, and $P_i=i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'}$. Applying BCH we get:
$U=e^{-iXP_1}e^{-iPP_2}e^{iP_1P_2/2}$
I tried playing around with that for a little while but couldn't seem to get anywhere, as when I expand the exponential in a power series $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2'}e^{-(x_1'^2+x_2'^2)}$ didn't seem to have a nice expression.

Comment: so $\langle x_1|\langle x_2|e^{-iXP_i}=\langle x_1|\langle x_2|e^{-i(x_1+x_2)P_i}$ (if I understand correctly that $X = X_1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes X_2$?). I haven't tried it, but as a next step I would put a completeness relation in momentum space in between to explicitly get some Fourier transforms

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I believe $X$ to be the position operator on $S$, while $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the position operators for the two meters which are separate systems. That's an interesting idea though about Fourier transforms, I might see if I can get anywhere with that.